# How to explain inverse modulo?

Tags: secondary-education, self-learning, calculations

Do you know a (simple) inverse modulo calculator somewhere on the Internet?

How to explain simply inverse modulo? (when the concept of modulo is already a bit known)

How to explain someone how to find a calculation resulting with a given modulo? For instance, finding a calculation with a modulo = 5.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good question for this site since it asks a question about how to calculate something instead of a question about mathematics education; you can find inverses modulo $n$ with the Euclidean Algorithm. See for example the "Extended Euclidean Algorithm" section at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Comment: And how to explain also... But do you think I should move my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first, there are a number of apps out there, though I will recommend that you go somewhat non-simple and use [Sage](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLVLBV8M1P0TDWMdfk5SooyswrUdBNhLES43QNAZxGCVk=&lang=sage).  Are you looking for additive or multiplicative inverse?  In either case, it is built-in.

```
a = Mod(3,7)
print -a
print a^-1
```

This gives `4` and `5`, respectively.